# Is there react native library which can transfer data between 2 mobile devices in offline mode?

Tags: react-native, cross-platform, offline, data-transfer

I am new to React Native development (for Android and iOS).

I am trying to transfer data between 2 mobile devices in offline mode (WiFi, Bluetooth or something else. QR codes no due to the data size limitations)

I found a good library `react-native-wifi-and-hotspot-wizard` and `react-native-wifi-hotspot` but it only supports Android, not iOS.

I am looking for a cross-platform (Android and iOS) data transfer library that can between 2 devices in offline mode.

Can anyone please suggest a library or some code tips?

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: this question is very similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424680/how-to-send-receive-data-over-wifi-without-internet-in-react-native

Comment: not quite sure but have you tried this library? https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-multipeer

Answer (score 0):

## ANDROID

you can use `react-native-wifi-p2p` library

https://github.com/kirillzyusko/react-native-wifi-p2p

```
yarn add react-native-wifi-p2p
```

you can use [sendFile](https://github.com/kirillzyusko/react-native-wifi-p2p#sendfilepathtofile) and [receiveFile](https://github.com/kirillzyusko/react-native-wifi-p2p#receivefilefolder-filename-forcetoscangallery) functions from this library for transfer files/data between 2 mobile devices

## IOS

for Ios, you can use  https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-multipeer#senddata-recipients--callbackerr

Comment: Thanks, but this library only works with Android. What I am looking for is to transfer data between any mobile device (between Androids or iOSs or between Android/iOS)

Comment: @Tom for ios you can use this library https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-multipeer#senddata-recipients--callbackerr

Comment: Yeah, I saw that… but that library hasn’t been updated in 6 years…

Comment: @Tom i think, we have to make new libary

Answer (score 0):

You can use my open source repo at `https://gitlab.com/amir1gorji/gorji`

There was a challenge to build such thing using React Native and I wrote the app in this repo.